# Reset numbers in multiple bibliographies with same entries biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need three bibliographies for my document. One with the articles, one with books and the last one with all the entries in the previous bibliographies. The style have to be `numeric` and every bibliography should start with `[1]`. My problem is that the numbers of the whole bibliography repeat the enumeration of the previous two, repeating numbers instead of a continuous enumeration.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ACohesion,
  author = {F. William Lawvere},
  title = {Axiomatic Cohesion},
  journal = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  year = {2007},
  volume = {19},
  number = {3},
  pages = {41-49},
  keywords={Lawvere}
}

@article{InternalChoice,
  author = {F. William Lawvere and Matías Menni},
  title = {Internal Choice Holds in the Discrete Part of any Cohesive Topos Stisfying Stable Connected Codiscretness},
  journal = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  year = {2015},
  volume = {30},
  number = {26},
  pages = {909-932},
  keywords={Lawvere}
}

@article{Remarks,
  author = {Peter T. Johnstone},
  title = {Remarks on Punctual Local Connectedness},
  journal = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {25},
  number = {3},
  pages = {51-63}
}

@book{SetsM,
  author = {F. William Lawvere and Robert Rosebrugh},
  title = {Sets for Mathematics},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  year = {2003},
  keywords = {Lawvere}
}

@book{SGL,
  author = {Saunders {Mac~Lane} and Ieke Moerdijk},
  title = {Sheaves in Geometry and Logic},
  publisher = {Springer},
  address = {},
  year = {1992}
}

@book{GaloisT,
  author = {Francis Borceux and George Janelidze},
  title = {Galois Theories},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  address = {Cambridge, UK},
  year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,defernumbers,giveninits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article, title=Articles]
\printbibliography[type=book, title=Books,resetnumbers]
\printbibliography[resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

and the output showing the undesired repetition in the References section (I want the enumeration going from `[1]` to `[6]` in this example):
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but how can you uniquely refer to a bibliographic entry in this way? If you write "see [1]" it could be the first [1] (an article) of the second [1] (a book).

Comment: @Ivan True, I haven’t think of that inconsistency. Your comment is enough for me to try to avoid that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a good way to do that if you want to be able to cite entries in your document. `biblatex` really needs a unique number for each entry. Plus, if you just relabel entries in different bibliographies your readers wouldn't know what number refers to which entry.

There are ways to get independent and separate labelling for the same entry if you use `refsection`s. But since `refsection`s are kept completely separate you would have to cite entries in several `refsection`s if you want them to appear in several lists.

If you don't need citations and just want to count entries in your bibliography, you can avoid `biblatex`-generated citation numbers completely and just base your bibliography on `enumarate`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,defernumbers,giveninits]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\enumerate}
  {\endenumerate}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ACohesion,
  author = {F. William Lawvere},
  title = {Axiomatic Cohesion},
  journal = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  year = {2007},
  volume = {19},
  number = {3},
  pages = {41-49},
  keywords={Lawvere}
}
@article{InternalChoice,
  author = {F. William Lawvere and Matías Menni},
  title = {Internal Choice Holds in the Discrete Part
           of any Cohesive Topos Stisfying Stable Connected Codiscretness},
  journal = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  year = {2015},
  volume = {30},
  number = {26},
  pages = {909-932},
  keywords={Lawvere}
}
@article{Remarks,
  author = {Peter T. Johnstone},
  title = {Remarks on Punctual Local Connectedness},
  journal = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {25},
  number = {3},
  pages = {51-63}
}
@book{SetsM,
  author = {F. William Lawvere and Robert Rosebrugh},
  title = {Sets for Mathematics},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  year = {2003},
  keywords = {Lawvere}
}
@book{SGL,
  author = {Saunders {Mac~Lane} and Ieke Moerdijk},
  title = {Sheaves in Geometry and Logic},
  publisher = {Springer},
  address = {},
  year = {1992}
}
@book{GaloisT,
  author = {Francis Borceux and George Janelidze},
  title = {Galois Theories},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  address = {Cambridge, UK},
  year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article, title=Articles]
\printbibliography[type=book, title=Books]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Numbered bibliographies.]

Comment: Thanks, even if is possible I’ll try to avoid it but thanks to take the time to do it